# How to use browser's form-data values in Angular with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

I have been trying to use browser's form-data option in my Angular App but not working properly.

It stores only `first user input` but browser is not remembering the second input onward...,

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-input-tfpf8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of my code.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <mat-form-field hintLabel="Max 50 characters" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    
        <input matInput #input2 formControlName="myName" id="myName" name="myName" maxlength="50" autocomplete="on">

        <mat-hint align="end">{{input2.value?.length || 0}}/50</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

What I tried?

```
id="myName" name="myName" autocomplete="on"
```

What else should I use?

Answer (score 0):

instead of just `'on'` you can specify the value of the autocomplete:

```
autocomplete="name"
```

The following prompted me with an autocomplete of my full name:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-input-nboebn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

For a full list of the values you can provide see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: It stores only `first user input` but is not remembering the second input onwards...,